# Access to fetch at 'https://www.google.com/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I would like to make a simple http request in javascript with `fetch()`, eg.:

```
async function fetchData() {
  const res = await fetch("https://www.google.com");
  console.log(res);
}

fetchData();
```

but this fails with:

> Access to fetch at 'https://www.google.com/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

There are lots of posts about this in internet and the most popular solutions revolve around setting up additional headers, I tried this as well, but it did not help:

```
const res = await fetch("https://www.google.com", {
    headers: {
      mode: "cors",
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
  });
}
// ...
```

This perfectly works with curl: `curl "https://www.google.com"`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the overarching problem that you are trying to solve with this code?

Comment: I would like to make an http request to a webpage and extract a subset of content from the html body.

Comment: So, it's a request to an `.html` page, not some protected API, so I am wondering why wouldn't it work?.. I should mention also that I have zero experience in web development, so maybe this is basic stuff. Is there a way to achieve what I want, i.e: download the content of a `.html` page?

Comment: You can fetch data from an API because that's what it is design to do, but html is blocked except under a narrow set of conditions. As an alternative, you might look at building a [browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/instant-data-scraper/ofaokhiedipichpaobibbnahnkdoiiah?hl=en) as those aren't limited by CORS. And extensions aren't difficult to [create](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/).

Comment: Yes CORS can be enabled using Headers, but they must be set by the server not the client.